# Bootstrap 4 set colour of headers of open panels

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

I'm using HTML templates, which are based on Bootstrap 4.3.1. With the help of the Stack Overflow community, I managed to change the default behaviour of the accordions in these templates. Now only one panel can be opened at a time (i.e. as soon as a new panel is opened, the previously opened panel will automatically close). I also managed to change the background colour of the active panel by invoking aria attributes as follows:

```
.accordion .card .card-header button[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color:#0965AC;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

A working example can be found on [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/hagelslag1001/pen/rNvLRxL) (the aforementioned code can be found at the bottom of the CSS:

When I open a specific panel on page load using `class="collapse show"`, the card-header of the open panel doesn't show the blue background. After closing and opening this panel again, the blue background shows.

Any suggestions on how I can, on page load, let the open panel also show the blue background?

I tried as follows, but no no avail:

```
.accordion .card .card-header button[class="collapse show"] {
  background-color:#0965AC;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your CSS you can change the `aria-expanded="false"` in your JavaScript to `aria-expanded="true"` depending on the element you want to be expanded. Replace the `$(value).find(...)` with the following to expand the first element on load:

```
if (num == 1) {
     $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title").wrapInner( "<button  class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" aria-expanded=\"true\"></button>");
} else {
     $(value).find(".card-header > .card-title").wrapInner( "<button  class=\"btn btn-link\" type=\"button\" data-toggle=\"collapse\" aria-expanded=\"false\"></button>");
}
```

There are two reasons why `.accordion .card .card-header button[class="collapse show"]` is not working. First of all, you would write `.accordion .card .card-header button.collapse.show` defining that the `button` element should have classes `collapse` and `show` in order for the button to get the CSS rules defined to this selector. Though, the button does not get these classes when it is clicked. You would need to toggle the `show` class on the button in order to see the CSS.

Comment: I replaced the part in js, and the result is great. After page load the header of the open accordion panel has the blue background. As a follow-up, how can accomplish this, when I have multiple, lets say an infinite number of accordions and each of those has its first panel open. I reckon I have to tinker with `if (num == 1) {`. This CodePen <https://codepen.io/hagelslag1001/pen/LYmbOZx> shows a page with two only accordions both with their first panels open after page load. Only the first has the blue background, because of `if (num == 1) {`

Comment: If you want to do that, it is much cleaner to give the parent (the `card`) a `.show` class when it is opened. Then you can set the color of the button using CSS `.card.show button.collapse` and the styling for the content using `.cord.show .card-body`. And you make sure that the `.show` class is toggled when a button is pressed. This means you need to do a bit of refactoring, but it will be cleaner.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to sit on it for a while. I guess I have to use js to toggle the class. JS sounds like French to me, but eventually I'll figure it out. Luckily for me there Stack Overflow.